# How do I change access modifiers applied to the class and methods generated by antlr4?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I don't want antlr's generated classes and methods exposed to the public API.

There's a 6-year old answer [Antlr generated classes access modifier to internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217952/antlr-generated-classes-access-modifier-to-internal). But I hope there's a more modern and true way to do it.

Comment: If your goal is to hide the generated classes from others in a commercial project, obfuscation is the only "modern and true" approach. Flipping public/internal is never the way.

Comment: No, not commerical. Just for general conveniance & for public api analyzers

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/blob/master/doc/README.md#extra-features-in-the-c-targets has the answer, but it doesn't work on antlr4

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't. You could use the `superClass` option in the grammar so that you extend a custom parser class where you define only those methods you want to be public:

```
grammar T;

options {
  superClass=MyParser;
}

parse
 : id+ EOF
 ;

id
 : ID
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
 ;
```

and your `MyParser` class could look like this:

```java
public abstract class MyParser extends Parser {

    public MyParser(TokenStream input) {
        super(input);
    }

    abstract TParser.ParseContext parse() throws RecognitionException;
}
```

and then instantiate your parser like this:

```java
TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("foo"));
MyParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.parse(); // OK
parser.id();    // No can do
```

> but I need to actually hide the whole class. This class should be internal, it's being called in inner methods in the lib

That is not something you can do AFAIK. You'll have to add that yourself with some post-build script (simple search/replace), I think.

Comment: Aha thanks, but I need to actually hide the whole class. This class should be internal, it's being called in inner methods in the lib